# jQuery click function not working after get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have been tackling this code for a while now, and I cannot get this click function to work in jQuery. I want a sidebar to go away when I click a close image. When I enter the click function in console it does seem to work. Also if I put the click function in the complete function of a get request that seems to work.

Javascript (Doesn’t work):

```
'use strict';

$.get('http://api.ipify.org?format=text&callback=?',
  function(text) {
    $('input[name="user_ip"]').val(text);
  }
);

$('.close-trigger').click(function() {
  $('aside.open').removeClass('open');
  return false;
});
```

Javascript (Works but isn’t neat):

```
'use strict';

$.get('http://api.ipify.org?format=text&callback=?',
  function(text) {
    $('input[name="user_ip"]').val(text);
$('.close-trigger').click(function() {
  $('aside.open').removeClass('open');
  return false;
});
  }
);
```

Sidebar HTML that I want to hide:

```
<aside id="sidebar">
      <h2>New proposal</h2>
      <a href="#" class="close-trigger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></a>
      <form id="proposal">
        <div>
          <label>Project name</label>
          <input name="project_name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Project description</label>
          <textarea name="project_desc" required>
          </textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#">Upload photo</a>
        </div>
        <!--
        <div id="details">
          <span></span>, <span></span>
        </div>
        -->
        <input type="text" name="user_ip" hidden>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </aside>
```

As I said if I paste the click function on console while the page is running the code works. I am not sure why this doesn’t work on it’s own though. Sorry for being such a specific question.

Comment: Put your script after `aside`. Or wrap it into `$(function() { /* your code */ })`.

Comment: You can't define DOM events, unless the DOM is ready.

Comment: @dfsq Thank you! I have no idea why that works though... You shouldn't need it in a wrapper surely? If you submit this as an answer I will accept it giving you 25 points....

Comment: @JamenMarz Make an answer and I will +1 it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that HTML page is downloaded and parsed synchronously. It means that if you put `script` tag in the `head`, the script gets executed at the moment when the `body` tag is not yet available. For this reason, if you attempt to bind click event before `aside` part of the HTML page is rendered, this will not work - because there is no `aside` in DOM tree.

To workaround this problem you have several options. Option number one, the simplest. You just put `<script>` tag before closing `</body>` tag. This way it's guarantied that DOM tree is fully available for binding events and DOM manipulations. Everything has already downloaded and rendered.

Option number two - listen for either [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) or [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) events. jQuery have a convenient shortcut for this. By wrapping your code into `$(function() { ... })` you actually subscribe to `DOMContentLoaded` event. So your code becomes:

```
$(function() {
    $.get('http://api.ipify.org?format=text&callback=?',
      function(text) {
        $('input[name="user_ip"]').val(text);
      }
    );

    $('.close-trigger').click(function() {
      $('aside.open').removeClass('open');
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I thought that DOM was already loaded, so this answer made lots of sense. I thought that the question was silly so I am on my alternate account so I cannot upvote your answer although it is so useful, thanks.

Comment: No worries, it's a good question. There is also a difference between window.onload and DOMContentLoaded events. Later will fire when HTML tree is rendered but before resources are downloaded (images, video, iframes), so it responds faster when window.onload. Finally, you can see often `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`. This is the same as shorter version `$(function() { ... })` for DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in an event that evaluates when the document is ready:

```
$(function(e){
  // Document is ready...
});
```

This needs to be done because you can't do something to the document via DOM if it's not ready yet.

It'd be like trying to read a paper, but they only printed half the words.